# Weak form of Elliptic problem with mixed Dirichlet & Neumann conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, boundary-value-problem, greens-theorem, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ in a bounded polygon domain and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ known function.We split the boundary into two parts $\partial \Omega_{1}$ and $\partial \Omega_{2}$ such that $\partial \Omega =\partial \Omega_{1} \cup \partial \Omega_{2}.$
The elliptic problem of  Dirichlet & Neumann conditions is :

\begin{align*}
-\Delta u +u &=f \quad in \quad \Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^2 \\
u&=0 \quad in \quad \partial \Omega_{1}   \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}}&=1 \quad in \quad \partial \Omega_{2} 
\end{align*}

It was asked to write the problem in a weak form in a suitable solution space $\mathcal{V}$ and the bilinear form $a(\cdot,\cdot):\mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V} \to \mathbb{R}$.

**My thought** :

\begin{align*}
-\Delta u+u &=f \\
-\Delta u v+uv &=fv \\
-\int_{\Omega}\Delta u v dV+ \int_{\Omega}uv dV&=\int_{\Omega}fv dV \\
\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV- \int_{\partial \Omega_{2}}v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n} dS  + \int_{\Omega}uv dV&=\int_{\Omega}fv dV \\
\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV- 1 + \int_{\Omega}uv dV&=\int_{\Omega}fv dV \\
\end{align*}
Is -1 right ?

Or :

$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV- \int_{\Omega} v dx + \int_{\Omega}uv dV=\int_{\Omega}fv dV$$

because $$\int_{\partial \Omega}v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n} dS = \int_{\Omega_{2}} v \cdot 1 dx$$

Is that correct ?
How you calculate the integral in a polygon domain such this one with these boundary conditions ?

**Solution**
\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial \Omega}v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n} dS &=\int_{\partial\Omega_{1}} v \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - \int_{\partial\Omega_{2}} v \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} dx \\
&=0 - \int_{\partial\Omega_{2}} v \cdot 1 dx \\
&=- \int_{\partial\Omega_{2}} v  dx
\end{align*}

$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV +\int_{\partial\Omega_{2}} v  dx + \int_{\Omega}uv dV=\int_{\Omega}fv dV$$

Comment: No, you should stick with the boundary integral $\int_{\partial \Omega_2} v$ and move it to the right hand side.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides how I will do this;

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides How I calculate the $\int_{d\Omega}v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n}dS$ ?Can someone calculate it in detail analytically please in order to understand the weak form of this divergence?I will be very glad.